# Images wont load on git hub pages despite working locally on my live server. I have checked paths and Capitilisation

Tags: github-pages

https://github.com/Roakz/portfolio-website

Hey guys. first time asker long timer reader. After completing my portfolio website for assessment and trying to host it for free on git hub. It is not displaying the images. They were visible in the live server no worries at all. Any help would be much appreciated the repo is above. cheers !! I have checked capitilisation and paths and cant seem to nail it on the head. Cheers.

Comment: I can see all the images load properly on your provided URL.

Comment: Thanks for having a look I just logged in now to update !! It was a file path issue ‍♂️ I needed to go up a directory ../ for some reason vs code and live server were loading the images fine like this ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved guys ! It was a file path error. For some reason Vs code and live server were loading them fine which is why I didn’t pick up on the error ‍♂️ a simple ../ is all that was needed .